# How do I write JUnit for my validator class in Java?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I heard that Mockito framework is really good for testing purposes.

Can anyone help me to write a good JUnit for below code.

```java
@Component
public class DataIntegrityValidatorForUpdate extends EmployeeCommonValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return Employee.class.equals(paramClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object targetObject, Errors errors) {
        if (!(targetObject instanceof Employee))
            return;

        Employee employee = (Employee) targetObject;
        Long employeeId = employee.getId();
        String tenantId = employee.getTenantId();

        // FIXME employee.getId == null or empty then throw error employee id is
        // required
        if (isEmpty(employeeId)) {
            errors.rejectValue("employee.id", "no value", "provide employee id for update");
            return;
        }

        if (!employeeRepository.checkIfEmployeeExists(employeeId, tenantId)) {
            // FIXME throw error employee id does not exist
            errors.rejectValue("employee.id", "no value present", "employee id doesn't exist");
            return;
        }

        validateEmployee(employee, errors);

        validateAssignments(employee.getAssignments(), employeeId, tenantId, errors);

    public void validateEmployee(Employee employee, Errors errors) {
        // FIXME call common validator.validateEmployee
        super.validateEmployee(employee, errors);

        // FIXME : check only for different employees

        if (checkIfColumnValueIsSameInDB("egeis_employee", "code", employee.getCode(), employee.getId(), employee.getTenantId())) {
            errors.rejectValue("employee.code", "invalid", "Employee Code cannot be changed.");
        }

        if ((employee.getPassportNo() != null) && duplicateExists("egeis_employee", "passportNo",   employee.getPassportNo(), employee.getId(), employee.getTenantId())) {
            errors.rejectValue("employee.passportNo", "concurrent", "passportNo already exists");
        }

        if ((employee.getGpfNo() != null) && duplicateExists("egeis_employee", "gpfNo", employee.getGpfNo(), employee.getId(), employee.getTenantId())) {
            errors.rejectValue("employee.gpfNo", "concurrent", "gpfNo already exists");
        }
    }


    private void validateAssignments(List<Assignment> assignments, Long employeeId, String tenantId, Errors errors) {
        validateIdsForAssignment(assignments, employeeId, tenantId, errors);

        for (int index = 0; index < assignments.size(); index++) {
            // validateDocumentsForNewAssignment(assignments.get(index),
            // errors, index);
        }
    }

    private void validateIdsForAssignment(List<Assignment> assignments, Long employeeId, String tenantId, Errors errors) {
        Map<Long, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < assignments.size(); index++) {
            if (assignments.get(index).getId() != null) // FIXME check if long
                                                    // gets default value of
                                                    // 0L
                idsMap.put(assignments.get(index).getId(), index);
        }
        if (!idsMap.isEmpty())
            validateEntityId(idsMap, EntityType.ASSIGNMENT, employeeId, tenantId, errors);
    }


    public Boolean duplicateExists(String table, String column, String value, Long id, String tenantId) {
        Long idFromDb = employeeRepository.getId(table, column, value, tenantId);
        if (idFromDb == 0 || id.equals(idFromDb))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean checkIfColumnValueIsSameInDB(String table, String column, String value, Long id, String tenantId) {
        Long idFromDb = employeeRepository.getId(table, column, value, tenantId);
        if (id.equals(idFromDb))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too broad - where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: And hint: you ask other people to spend their time to help you. And then you walk away, without giving any feedback. Would you consider that being polite behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Given your production code, writing tests is pretty simple; like:

```
public class DataIntegrityValidatorForUpdateTest {

@Mock
Errors mockedErrors;
@Mock
EmployeeRepository mockedRepository;

@InjectMocks
DataIntegrityValidatorForUpdate underTest;

@Before
public void setup() {
  initMocks();
}

@Test
public void testNotAnEmployee() {
  underTest.validate("not an employee", mockedErrors);
  verifyZeroInteractions(mockedRepository, mockedErrors);
}
```

What this does:

- it mocks the *two* objects you need to control in order to test this class
- it uses the @InjectMocks annotation to instantiate an instance of the class you intend to test
- it then tests *one* aspect of your method - the method is invoked with parameters that should cause the method to return and do nothing

The above is meant as inspiration. Now **you** have to enhance it, to cover all the possible paths that your method can take. Most of your test methods would look similar; but you will have to learn how to use Mockito to **verify** that certain calls on your mock objects came in.

But please do **not** expect that we do that for you. It is your project, and you have to study the [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html) and [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) to understand what **you** need to do.

Beyond that: from a clean code perspective, I would suggest you to refactor the whole thing. I would rather throw **exceptions** to indicate failed validations; instead of using an in/out parameter like `errors`.